# Dynamic tab doesn't show content Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Currently I have 6 tabs that are dynamically populated from the Post Categories in Wordpress. https://nationalvip.pixl.work/webinars/

When I click each of them they should be displaying the posts belonging to that category selected.

Problem is If I click any of them the one selected doesn't show the anything.

here is my javascript code (which i took it from here: [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_vertical_tabs):

```
function openCity(evt, cityName) {

    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
 }

    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

I've done some tests, and found that the "active" class is not added to the selected tab. Although this same code works on codepen here: [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/blue_ssandro/pen/ExZrqqY)

You can see my current demo here: https://nationalvip.pixl.work/webinars/

I really appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps someone with same issue:

the problem was this line:`document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";`

I updated that line with this one: `cityName.style.display = "block";`

we need to use the value received on the cityName which contain the ID of the block to be displayed.